# Cannot access SVN Repository from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I had to do some server maintenance on Amazon Web Services. which involved increasing capacity and assigning an Elastic IP (Static IP). To do this I had to Stop the Instance, do the maintenance and Start the instance again.

I then updated my SSH config file with the new host name details. I can SSH into the server with no issues.

But I cannot reconnect to the SVN via Eclipse, I get the following error:

svn: E175002: connection refused by the server

Any help appreciated, I'm stuck on this issue and not sure what to do next.

**EDIT**

I tried using the following command:

```
svn switch --relocate [Old IP Address] [New IP Address]
```

but I get the following error:

```
svn: E155007: '/var/svn' is not a working copy
```

Regards,
Steve

Comment: What protocol do you use to access subversion? https maybe?
Running SVN on an elastic host sounds like a bad idea to me...

Comment: No just http, why is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks to AWS support.

So I had to restart the web service using the following command:

```
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

and then to avoid having this problem in the future, I ran this command which will automatically restart the web service if I need to stop/start the server:

```
sudo service httpd start
```